# Java: Saving canvas to an image file results in a blank image

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage

I have a class that extends `Canvas` and implements the below methods. The problem is, that whenever I call `exportImage`, all I get is a blank white image. There should be drawings on the image.

```
/**
  * Paint the graphics
  */
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    rows = sim.sp.getRows();
    columns = sim.sp.getColumns();
    createBufferStrategy(1);
    // Use a bufferstrategy to remove that annoying flickering of the display
    // when rendering
    bf = getBufferStrategy();
    g = null;
    try{
        g = bf.getDrawGraphics();
        render(g);
    } finally {
        g.dispose();
    }
    bf.show();
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();    
}

/**
 * Render the cells in the frame with a neat border around each cell
 * @param g
 */
private Graphics render(Graphics g) {
    // Paint the simulation onto the graphics...

}

/**
  * Export the the display area to a file
  * @param imageName the image to save the file to
  */
public void exportImage(String imageName) {
    BufferedImage image = new  BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();
    paintAll(graphics);
    graphics.dispose();
    try {
        System.out.println("Exporting image: "+imageName);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageName);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", out);
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `render` instead of `paint` in the `exportImage` method to print the graphics to the image. Seems like it was a problem with the `bufferStrategy` I used.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your `paint` method to be as simple as the one below and the export is working fine. However, I suggest you override `paintComponent` rather than `paint`:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawRect(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `paint` method, instead of `paintAll`

```
public void exportImage(String imageName) {
    BufferedImage image = new  BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();
    paint(graphics);
    graphics.dispose();
    try {
        System.out.println("Exporting image: "+imageName);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageName);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", out);
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: When I used `paint` the saved image was entirely black which is not what was in the canvas.